# fragment to activity animation does not work with overridePendingTransition();

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation

I want to switch the animation when I switch from a `fragment` to an activity but the function

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

is red marked with `Cannot resolve method` in the `fragment`.

In activities it works fine. How can I make it work?

Comment: which fragment do you use V4 or simple fragment?

Comment: Wherever you have the code in your fragment that starts the transition, you can communicate from the fragment to your activity that you want to do so (via interface) and in the receiver method of the activity, invoke the overridePendingTransition method as you'd normally do for activity transitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is red marked with Cannot resolve method `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );` in the fragment.

**Because** `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );` method of Activity not of `Fragment`

Try this

```
  getActivity().overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```